# HTML Encoding and PHP

Tags: php, html, encoding

Hello im using php i need to compare data from my array and data from readed captcha. But i got problem with html encoding. Example from my array:

```
"osiemnaście" => 18,
```

and data from captcha:

```
osiemna&#x015b;cie
```

How can compare these data ? I already tried "html_entity_decode()" but no results.

Comment: Consider not using accented characters for captchas, those things can already be confusing enough without having to figure out that random flying dots are part of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to decode hex entities you'll have to work it a bit, since PHP built-in function does not cover these.

```
$string = "osiemna&#x015b;cie";
$string = preg_replace('/\&\#x([a-fA-F0-9]+)\;/me', 'mb_convert_encoding("&#".hexdec("\\1").";", "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES")', $string);

// $string is now  "osiemnaście"

echo ($string == "osiemnaście")
   ? "success"
   : "failure";
```

Comment: Before preg_replace: "pi&#x0119;&#x0107;" 
after: "pi"
I dont know why.

Comment: Well, after some research it looks like the entities are actually unicodes (U+xxxx) but presented as hex.

Comment: I've updated with an alternative for converting unicode to html encoding. Try my answer now.

Comment: @user2796493 Sorry! I forgot to remove the "x" from the encoded entity! Now it should work without issues, its been tested!

Comment: Thanks, You are my hero! :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a character-set/encoding issue with that accented 's' character.  Make sure you're setting UTF-8 on both the server and on the HTML side.

It's been a while since I've done a lot of PHP, but this function might be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

You option would be to do it the other way round:

```
htmlentities("osiemnaście") == $captchainput
```

You have to care about your file- and input-encoding from the htmldocument.

You can define the documentencoding using php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or in html: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`